# Production build cannot find environment info, but dev builds without errors

Tags: angular, firebase, webpack, angular7

I have an angular 7 app that when building in dev mode it compiles and is served without errors. But, when I build the app with production settings it compiles without issue, but it cannot find the environment information and just errors in browser.

```
vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1 ERROR ReferenceError: env is not defined
    at new n (main.04dfe8e133fc5e316d84.js:1)
    at Vs (vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1)
    at Ms (vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1)
    at mu (vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1)
    at hu (vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1)
    at Object.Du [as createRootView] (vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1)
    at e.create (vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1)
    at e.create (vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1)
    at t.bootstrap (vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1)
    at vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1
mi @ vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1
vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: env is not defined
ReferenceError: env is not defined
    at new n (main.04dfe8e133fc5e316d84.js:1)
    at Vs (vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1)
    at Ms (vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1)
    at mu (vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1)
    at hu (vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1)
    at Object.Du [as createRootView] (vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1)
    at e.create (vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1)
    at e.create (vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1)
    at t.bootstrap (vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1)
    at vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1
    at M (polyfills.65f19a590318fc6860f7.js:1)
    at polyfills.65f19a590318fc6860f7.js:1
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.65f19a590318fc6860f7.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.d1094f98a9a59a44ad59.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.65f19a590318fc6860f7.js:1)
    at e.runTask (polyfills.65f19a590318fc6860f7.js:1)
    at g (polyfills.65f19a590318fc6860f7.js:1)
```

Building in dev mode works as intended. Not sure why production is any different. No errors present in the terminal.

Expected prod build to be consistent with dev build

Comment: Did you fill the environment.prod.ts with the same data as that environment.ts?

Comment: Yes, the files were the same and no errors existed in the environment files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the offending statement:

`import { environment as env } from '@env/environment';`

To correct the error, simply remove the alias and update that line (and any reference) to:

`import { environment } from '@env/environment';`

Does anyone know why using the `as env` syntax caused this issue?

Comment: I had this error as well not so long ago, be interested to know why this causes run time errors in prod builds

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something is going on with your `environment.prod.ts` file in `environments/environment.prod.ts` make sure this matches your `environment.ts` file.
When you build with prod `environment.prod.ts` replaces `environment.ts`.
Have a look at the naming in the two files, looks like maybe in your `environment.prod.ts` you may have

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    etc...
}
```

instead of

```
export const env = {
    production: true,
    etc...
}
```

Looks like thats the error from the prompt. 
http://tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/ is a good url for getting to know environments in angular better.

Comment: This was a good suggestion and where I began my debugging, but the files were the same and the compiled app had the correct prod info in the main.js file